Why is Pre-pipeline var $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME empty in "New pipeline in the GitLab UI"?
I'm trying to display different global variables according the selected branch (main/windows/linux) in the GitLab UI when you run the pipeline by clicking "New pipeline in the GitLab UI".
For that I'm using the Pre-pipeline variable $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME, but it's empty.
It's working with Pre-pipeline variable $CI_PROJECT_NAME
I'm expecting to see the the variables of the included files according the selected branch.
But the variable is empty, so only the variables of .gitlab-ci.yml, main.yml, byprojectname.yml are shown.
Do I have to use a different variable?
Is it not working in my GitLab version (16.11)?
Do I miss something else?
I tried using variables with include and include with rules:if.
Both not working with $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME because it's empty.
Example:
# .gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - local: main.yml # Working

  - local: byprojectname.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PROJECT_NAME == "myproject" # Working

  - local: linux.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "linux" # Not working
      # - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "linux" # Not working

  # - local: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.yml" # Not working
  # - local: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH.yml" # Not working

variables:
  GITLAB_CI_VAR:
    value: "GITLAB_CI_VAR"
    description: "GITLAB_CI_VAR"

test:
  script:
    - echo "GITLAB_CI_VAR '${GITLAB_CI_VAR}'"
    - echo "MAIN_VAR '${MAIN_VAR}'"
    - echo "BYPROJECTNAME_VAR '${BYPROJECTNAME_VAR}'"
    - echo "LINUX_VAR '${LINUX_VAR}'"
    - echo "WINDOWS_VAR '${WINDOWS_VAR}'"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"

# main.yml
variables:
  MAIN_VAR:
    value: "MAIN_VAR"
    description: "MAIN_VAR"


# byprojectname.yml
variables:
  BYPROJECTNAME_VAR:
    value: "BYPROJECTNAME_VAR"
    description: "BYPROJECTNAME_VAR"

# linux.yml
variables:
  LINUX_VAR:
    value: "LINUX_VAR"
    description: "LINUX_VAR"

# windows.yml
variables:
  WINDOWS_VAR:
    value: "WINDOWS_VAR"
    description: "WINDOWS_VAR"

Run Pipeline Main
Run Pipeline Linux
